# Has anyone been able to communicate between BlackBerry and Android phones via NFC?

Tags: android, blackberry, nfc

I have been trying to do some basic communications between a BlackBerry and a Android NFC enabled phone. The BlackBerry is a Bold 9930 with 7.1 on it, and the Android is a Nexus S with 2.3.6 on it. I have the BlackBerry set up to emulate a tag and am trying to get the Android phone to recognize it. I have a NXP test board set up and it can read the BB emulated tag's ID, but the Android won't recognize it. Has anyone been able to do this successfully?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, I just used the Smart Tags app on a BlackBerry 9360 with OS7.0 to create a Smart Poster tag and place it in tag emulation mode.  Then held it to the back of a Nexus S running NXPs tag writer app, and it recognised and read the BB emulated tag.  Likewise the tag was read on the Nexus S by the NFC TagInfo app by Michael Roland at NFC Research Lab.

Comment: A quick question, have you been able to emulate a Type 4 Tag and pass NDEF messages between the two?

Comment: Ben, good question, I will investigate further, both with the native Smart Tags app, and my own (in development) app, and get back to you.

Answer (score 1):

You have a good example at [blackberry doc](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/34480/Near_Field_Communication_1631111_11.jsp#Emulating_smart_tags_1735746_11). You can share a NDEF message to the Android phone. Is a simple example but the communication is possible.

Comment: Thank you, I will be trying this out.